# terminal escape sequences for fonts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

**What I want to develop**:
Terminal which can use at least 2 fonts in the same time. One font I will use for shell input lines, another font for command output. For example:

```
user@host$ ls /home
user user1 user2 user3
```

**Why**:
More readable terminal/shell

**How**: Here I have problem. Probably shell needs to generate some new escape sequences. And terminal need to load different fonts and handle those sequences. Where to start? How to define new escaping sequence, where are standards?

**Future**: Maybe somebody want to join me in this project?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think this would need something from your terminal emultor as well. Simple bold/italics/underline would probably be available with shell escapes, but font change looks difficult.

Comment: You can already use colored prompts... also, I've never noticed that "terminal/shell" are not "readable".

Comment: anishsane: if we can use "no monospace" font for shell command line, and "monospace" for all outputs, it would significantly improve look&feel.

Comment: gniourf_gniourf: you have never get lost in terminal output? colors are nice especially if not overused. but our eyes and brain are better in recognizing  small shape differences. Anyway, if we can change colors, italization, underlining of terminal font why not to make full functionality of changing font?

Comment: One pointer: `bash` doesn't really treat the prompt and the user's input specially; the prompt is just written to standard error (which can be observed by redirecting the shell's standard error). Your shell wouldn't necessarily have to do this; it could write to a third internal file descriptor (which of course would default to the terminal, like standard error and standard output). Then you can write whatever terminal control characters you like to this dedicated prompt file descriptor, and the problem reduces to having a terminal emulator that can interpret them correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard for control sequences is pretty much the Xterm Control Sequences document [ctlseqs.ms](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.pdf) in the [XTerm source code](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/). (You can turn it into a PDF with the command `groff -ms -Tps ctlseqs.ms | ps2pdf - ctlseqs.pdf`, though the `-ms` option seems to be broken on Ubuntu 12.04).

XTerm already supports control sequences to change the font, but for the entire terminal at once. Open `xterm` and type into your shell—

```
echo -e "\033[?35h\033]50;#+1^G\033\\" # aka CSI ? 35 h OSC 50 ; #+1 BEL ST
```

the font for the entire terminal should change. This control sequence actually supports the names of True-Type fonts as well; see page 21.

If you'd like to change an existing terminal to support changing the font inline, you're 
welcome to choose pretty much any control sequences not already allocated in `ctrlseqs.ms` and use them. However, it's a good idea to choose new control sequences similar to the control sequences for functionality that already exists.

Your next step is to get the source code for an existing terminal and start digging. What terminal do you use right now? The source code for [Konsole](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kde-baseapps/konsole/repository) or [gnome-terminal](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-terminal/tree/) is probably going to be easier to work with than that for XTerm.

Comment: Most of the time I'm using urxvt. I would start probably from there. But gnome-terminal has big audience (of beginner users) so that would be my second target.

Comment: "If you'd like to change an existing terminal to support changing the font inline, you're welcome to choose pretty much any control sequences not already allocated in ctrlseqs.ms"
Err.. No. There are already existing sequences defined to do exactly this. They are SGR 10 (to reset to the default font), and SGR 11 to SGR 19 to select alternative fonts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard sequence for swapping fonts.

```
SGR 11
```

Also known as

```
CSI 11m
ESC [ 11m
```

Similarly

```
SGR 10
```

will switch back to the default font.

However, as has been commented, almost no terminal actually supports this. You'd likely be better off using some other rendering attribute, such as bold/underline/italics. Though note also not many terminals support italics.

For reference

```
SGR 1   = bold
SGR 4   = underline
SGR 3   = italics
```

Comment: Thanks! According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) SGR from 11 to 19 are alternative fonts. Maybe some terminal has ready -fontN support.. BTW, this [link](http://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/SGR) says that SGR is for changing character sets. Not fonts.

Comment: Maybe it will be easy to add new fonts to terminal like urxvt for the beginning... Changing font in X window shouldn't be big problem...

Comment: pangoterm/libvterm already support exactly this. See also https://launchpad.net/pangoterm  specifically the screenshots in http://leonerds-code.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/libvtermpangoterm-and-tickit.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with just different font attributes (and not different fonts) you can even implement something similar without writing your own terminal emulator if you use zsh. You can just set up your shell to emit the right escape sequences to set the correct terminal attribute (italics, bold, color, ...) before and after the prompt and before command execution.

Let's assume you use Xterm and want your prompt to be bold, the typed command line to be italics and the command output to be normal.

Then the setup looks like this:

```
# bold is \e[1m and italics is \e[3m , \e[0m resets the attributes
PS1=$'\e[1m'$PS1$'\e[0;3m' # I assume you have set PS1 already
function reset-terminal-attributes { printf '\e[0m'; }
autoload add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook preexec reset-terminal-attributes
```